# Mechanical button presser for tactile switch

Tags: arduino, switches

I'm trying to create a small Arduino project where I have to attach it on an appliance that has a tactile switch. I want this to be detachable/modular solution that way I can re-use it on other appliances with little or no modification needed. But i'm not sure what component do I use that will do the pressing to those switches.

Is there a pre-made component that can do a push function or do I use servos to mechanically do that? Is there a similar projects on the internet that is similar to my problem?

[image]

Comment: When you say "appliance" do you mean a mains-supplied appliance?

Comment: sorry, I meant electrical appliances (e.g. microwave). I might have been too generic. Here's an example of those buttons http://i63.tinypic.com/2wqbneg.jpg

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a solenoid. It's a linear actuator which uses the electromagnetic effect to pull on a pin. This pin could be used to push a simple button. https://www.adafruit.com/product/412 << something like this should foot the bill

Comment: Yes, I think this will work! Do you also happen to know something more compact than this? I just find it too tall? It's just for aesthetics :) If not, I think this will do. Again, thank you! :)

Comment: It would not be too hard to rig up a L-shape hinged lever that translate the horizontal motion (of a horizontal mounted solenoid) to vertical motion. It would also give you a place to trade off the travel distance vs force.